# "Unrecognized app. Please make sure you trust this app before proceeding" in flutter stripe payment

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies, android-9.0-pie

i'm beginner for flutter. i need connect stripe payment and flutter. so i use  stripe_payment: ^1.0.6(https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/stripe_payment/versions/1.0.6). using this example i tried to build payment gate way. but their has error "Unrecognized app. Please make sure you trust this app before proceeding".

[image]

After that press the continuous button it provide,

[image]   error.

In my widget button has following codes,

```
void _payWithCard() {
StripePayment.createSourceWithParams(SourceParams(
  type: 'ideal',
  amount: 333,
  currency: 'eur',
  returnURL: 'projectXXXXX://payment_redirect',
)).then((source) {
  setState(() {
    _source = source;
  });
}).catchError(setError);
```

}

their has some codes related with my Stripe payment gateway.

```
@override
```

void initState() {
    super.initState();

```
StripePayment.setOptions(StripeOptions(
    publishableKey: "piok_test_pIoKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxTzgP009ywg8JNs",
    merchantId: "projectXXXXXsolutions",
    androidPayMode: 'test'));
initPlatformState();
```

}

```
  initPlatformState() async {
if (_type == UniLinksType.string) {
  await initPlatformStateForStringUniLinks();
} else {
  await initPlatformStateForUriUniLinks();
}
print('init platform state');
```

}

```
// Attach a second listener to the stream
getLinksStream().listen((String link) {
  print(' got link success: $link');
  lartChechOutLoading(context);
}, onError: (err) {
  print('got err: $err');
});
// Get the latest link
String initialLink;
Uri initialUri;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  initialLink = await getInitialLink();
  print('initial link: $initialLink');
  if (initialLink != null) initialUri = Uri.parse(initialLink);
} on PlatformException {
  initialLink = 'Failed to get initial link.';
  initialUri = null;
} on FormatException {
  initialLink = 'Failed to parse the initial link as Uri.';
  initialUri = null;
}


// If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
// message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
// setState to update our non-existent appearance.
if (!mounted) return;

setState(() {
  _latestLink = initialLink;
  _latestUri = initialUri;
});
```

}

```
// Get the latest Uri
Uri initialUri;
String initialLink;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  initialUri = await getInitialUri();
  print('initial uri: ${initialUri?.path}'
      ' ${initialUri?.queryParametersAll}');
  initialLink = initialUri?.toString();
} on PlatformException {
  initialUri = null;
  initialLink = 'Failed to get initial uri.';
} on FormatException {
  initialUri = null;
  initialLink = 'Bad parse the initial link as Uri.';
}
```

  -

Comment: Are these your credentials? Please remove them.

Comment: those are fake credentials.

Comment: I'd suggest checking [Google troubleshooting docs](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/support/troubleshooting#unrecognized-app) which cover that error.

Answer (score 0):

This little note is shown while operating in `TEST` mode, and inform your users that your application hasn't gone through the process of being approved in [Google Pay's Business Console](https://pay.google.com/business/console) (see the [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/support/troubleshooting) to learn more).

Also, I'd recommend taking a look at the [new official Flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) built by the community in collaboration with Stripe. If you are using other payment providers, you can also easily add Apple and Google Pay to your Flutter applications with the [pay plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/pay).